# How can I specify Account ID in CDK when I'm authorized with temp credentials to the AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I have seen related questions for this issue.

But my problem in particular is I am assuming a role to retrieve temporary credenitals. It works just fine; however, when running CDK Bootstrap, I receive: Need to perform AWS calls for account <account_id>, but no credentials have been configured.

I have tried using CDK Deploy as well and I receive: Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment

How can I specify AWS Account enviornment in CDK when using temp credentials or assuming role?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the account you are attempting to bootstrap too.

for [bootstrap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html) you can use it as part of the command - `cdk bootstrap aws://ACCOUNT-NUMBER-1/REGION-1 aws://ACCOUNT-NUMBER-2/REGION-2 ...`  do note that a given account/region only ever has to be bootstrapped ONCE in its lifetime, no matter how many cdk stacks are going to be deployed there.

AND your credentials need to be part of the default profile. If you are assuming credentials through some sort of enterprise script, please check with them that they store it as part of the default profile. If not, run at least `aws config` in your bash terminal and get your temp assumed credentials in there

For `cdk deploy` you need to make sure in your `app.py` that you have the [env defined](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html)

```
env_EU = cdk.Environment(account="8373873873", region="eu-west-1")
env_USA = cdk.Environment(account="2383838383", region="us-west-2")

MyFirstStack(app, "first-stack-us", env=env_USA)
MyFirstStack(app, "first-stack-eu", env=env_EU)
```

i would however recommend against hardcoding your account numbers ;)

Comment: Actually, hardcoding account numbers is a preferred method in the CDK. It leads to deterministic code and that's "A Good Thing"

Comment: Hardcoding account numbers is NOT good security practice. Zero Trust, and that is information that is part of the puzzle.

Comment: there are certain features of the CDK which you will really struggle against if you aren't comfortable putting an AWS account number in there. One way around that is by having it be an env variable, like `process.env.PROD_ACCOUNT`

Comment: You do know that a Stack has an account attribute right? `this.Account` within a Stack Construct? You don't have to pass any account numbers around anywhere, the Stack can determine it from the aws cli config profile in your synth/deployment location. If you're using a code build or code deploy it will know it automatically, if local you can add it without the number ever being hardcoded

Comment: Yup. And if you're in a construct you can use Stack.of(this).account (get the stack first). But I don't think that's what the original question was asking. As for hardcoding the account numbers, as you recommended against, this is actually part of the best practices (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html). Read the section on 'Model all production stages in code'. To do this, you'd have to provide account numbers and not just retrieve them from the environment.

Answer (score 0):

the name of credential and config file should be the same
like:

```
-credentials
[cdk]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxx
-config
[cdk]
region = "us-east-1"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).